# How to show Name in gmail inbox - PHP

Tags: php, gmail

EMAIL ID showing as Name in GMAIL INBOX. Please solve this issue. 
using PHP code..
I want to see persons name.

MY CODINGS :

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
// Checking For Blank Fields..
if($_POST["vname"]==""||$_POST["vemail"]==""||$_POST["sub"]==""||$_POST["msg"]==""){
echo "Fill All Fields..";
}else{
// Check if the "Sender's Email" input field is filled out
$email=$_POST['vemail'];
// Sanitize E-mail Address
$email =filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
// Validate E-mail Address
$email= filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
if (!$email){
echo "Invalid Sender's Email";
}
else{
$subject = $_POST['sub'];
$message = $_POST['msg'];
$headers = 'From:'. $email . "\r\n"; // Sender's Email
$headers .= 'Cc:'. $email . "\r\n"; // Carbon copy to Sender
// Message lines should not exceed 70 characters (PHP rule), so wrap it
$message = wordwrap($message, 70);
// Send Mail By PHP Mail Function
mail("hameed.basha278@gmail.com", $subject, $message, $headers);
echo "Your mail has been sent successfuly ! Thank you for your feedback";
}
}
}
?>
```

Comment: where is your Reply To header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append the reply to header

`$headers.='Reply-To: '.$_POST["vname"].'<"'.$email.'">'. "\r\n";`

Comment: Please describe in detail

Comment: @Coder_Hameed what's to describe?

Comment: what don't you understand?

Comment: your self, what do you need to change?

Comment: yes tell me where should i swift your codings into mine

Comment: you don't know where to put this code?

Comment: you need to put it after `$headers .= 'Cc:'. $email . "\r\n"; // Carbon copy to Sender`

Comment: thanks for your reply..it solved !!!

Comment: Please solve my second question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46829373/how-to-send-attachments-in-form-to-gmail-inbox-php